# Java - Why Iterator need to be generic?

Tags: java, collections

Iterators of the actual List are implemented as inner classes in the List's class. Therefore we can refer to the List's generic type from the inner class. So why iterators are generic? If we call an iterator from the actual List, the next() method will use the Generic type of the List the iterator was called from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator interface is designed as

```
public interface Iterator<E> {
    boolean hasNext();
    E next();
    void remove();
}
```

Note the `next` method. What return type would it have, if the interface weren't generic? It would be

```
Object next();
```

So without parameterization you would end up with code like this:

```
List<String> list = createSomeList();
String s = (String) list.iterator().next();
```

Note the necessary cast. The whole point of generics is to produce code without the need to cast; this is called *type safety*. With the current iterator interface you can do

```
List<String> list = createSomeList();
String s = list.iterator().next();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because we override a method from the superclass. If the superclass didn't provide a generic signature, you couldn't override it with a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't given that ALL iterators are implemented as inner classes. Even if it were so, the instance of returned iterator would still be obtained from the type of the collection type (List, in your case)

The **key** point however is linked to the contract between List and its callers. List/Collection.iterator() should return the a generic iterator based on its type parameter [whether you used an intermediate variable to store the iterator or not].